# How to keep clean url after redirection

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I used the following `.htaccess` codes to redirect to a dirty `url`.

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^cap/?$    

https://docs.google.com/a/l5lab.com/forms/d/1gTVPzkBSyKAiLNv26MhVlfGfYf78AgNY0OWA0PQm3lY
/viewform    [NC,L]
```

It works fine. But when it redirects, it changes to the dirty `url`. How can I keep the clean `url` on the address bar after the redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "keep the clean url" for a url that exists on a different server.  One of the only ways to have a "clean url" is to use an iframe like this:

**/cap.html**

```
<iframe frameBorder="0" src="https://docs.google.com/a/l5lab.com/forms/d/1gTVPzkBSyKAiLNv26MhVlfGfYf78AgNY0OWA0PQm3lY/viewform"
    style="width: 100%; height: 2210px;"></iframe>
```

Comment: It’s not the _only_ way, one could use `mod_proxy` or something; but I’m not sure if Google would approve of this “use case”.

Comment: Very true. thanks @CBroe. I've updated my post to reflect that